# Pointer to qualified and non-qualified type representation

Tags: c++, c, constants, language-lawyer

Is it safe to reinterpret a pointer to an unqualified type as a pointer to a qualified type? Consider a standard layout type containing a pointer member "void *ptr" and another standard layout type defined equivalently, but with "const void *ptr". Are these types layout compatible, and does this answer depend on the language revision or between C and C++?

Motivation:

Sometimes when interfacing with C programs, one defines a struct grouping parameters to some type of buffer. For const-correctness, an input buffer should have const pointers to underlying buffers, but output buffers must obviously be mutable.

```
struct s1 { const void *ptr; }
struct s2 { void *ptr; }

const void *get_in_ptr(void);
void *get_out_ptr(void);

void alg(const s1 *in, const s2 *out);

void f()
{
    s1 in_arg = { get_in_ptr() };
    s2 out_arg1 = { get_out_ptr() };
    s2 out_arg2 = { get_out_ptr() };

    /* First algorithm pass. */
    alg(&in_arg, &out_arg1);
    /* Second algorithm pass. */
    alg((const s1 *)&out_arg1, &out_arg2); /* Is this legal? */
}
```

Please cite the relevant standard publications in any answers.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. `get_in_ptr` and `get_out_ptr` are not defined.

Comment: I have extended the example.

Answer (score 2):

C11 [states](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p1):

> For any qualifier q, a pointer to a non-q-qualified type may be converted to a pointer to the q-qualified version of the type; the values stored in the original and converted pointers shall compare equal.

So, it is safe to cast to a qualified version, but not vice-versa. Casting away - especially `const` or volatile could use different memory accesses, e.g. for Harvard architectures storing `const` variables in program memory (PIC, AVR). And the standard is very [clear](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.3p6) about the consequences:

> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined. If an attempt is made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-volatile-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.

Briefly: it is **not** safe to cast away those qualifiers in general. The standard does not mention read-accesses for ex-`const` objects, however.

For the other qualifiers and further details, please read yourself.

---

For the struct layout: C uses compatibility by type/layout, as opposed to C++. So two types are compatible if they use the same layout/standard type, not the same type-name.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is whether the cast _itself_ (which is done by casting a pointer to one struct into a pointer to a different struct) is safe, not whether writing to the value referenced through the pointer it safe.

Comment: @Random832 I agree. The question is regarding whether it is defined to cast the pointers to structs containing pointers of different qualification and read the values of those pointers (not the pointed object).

Comment: @68ejxfcj5669: The question is clearly given in the first paragraph: "Is it safe to reinterpret a pointer to a qualified type as a pointer to a non-qualified type? ...". Note that C does not have a `reinterpret_cast`, but only a cast. If you have a problem with a C answer, you should have tagged your question C++ only.

Comment: But the question is about casting pointers to two different structs and whether those two structs are compatible for the purpose of such a cast based on the pointer qualifications _of their members_.

Comment: @Random832: Read the paragraph! OP should have asked different if she wants a different answer. Problem is also that OP is missing some information and a comprehensive answer depends on the language. C is not C++. Especially with type-compatibility, there are massive differences.

Comment: @Olaf Yes, the question in the first paragraph is very clear. Is it valid to interpret a memory object containing a pointer to unqualified as a memory object containing a pointer to qualified, and vice-versa? The question of whether such pointers are convertible or not by some language mechanism is irrelevant.

Answer (score -2):

> `[C99: 6.2.5/25, C11: 6.2.5/26]:` *[..]* The qualified or unqualified versions of a type are distinct types that belong to the same type category and have the same representation and alignment requirements. *[..]*
>
> `[C++03, C++11, C++14: 3.9.3/1]:` *[..]* The cv-qualified or cv-unqualified versions of a type are distinct types; however, they shall have the same representation and alignment requirements (3.11).

And for the encapsulating types:

> `[C99: 6.2.7/1]:` *[..]* Moreover, two structure, union, or enumerated types declared in separate translation units are compatible if their tags and members satisfy the following requirements: If one is declared with a tag, the other shall be declared with the same tag. If both are complete types, then the following additional requirements apply: there shall be a one-to-one correspondence between their members such that each pair of corresponding members are declared with compatible types, and such that if one member of a corresponding pair is declared with a name, the other member is declared with the same name. *[..]*
>
> `[C++03: 9.2/14]:` Two POD-struct (clause 9) types are layout-compatible if they have the same number of nonstatic data members, and corresponding nonstatic data members (in order) have layout-compatible types (3.9).
>
> `[C++11: 9.2/16, C++14: 9.2/17]:` Two standard-layout struct (Clause 9) types are layout-compatible if they have the same number of non-static data members and corresponding non-static data members (in declaration order) have layout-compatible types (3.9).

So, assuming we're ignoring the type system bypass (`const void*` → `void*` through `const_cast` either directly or by C-style cast — note that `reinterpret_cast` has nothing to do with this and is explicitly prohibited from dropping *cv-qualifiers*) and only talking about aliasing compatibility…

**…yes, this is "safe".**

It's why we're able to use `const_cast`, delicately, when ancient C APIs force us to take them at their word rather than actually using `const`-safety.

You know this is okay anyway, because when you wrote `&in_arg` your compiler implicitly converted the `s1*` to `const s1*` for the call, and did not complain.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Should I interpret this as meaning that the structs "s1" and "s2" are layout compatible (or the equivalent C terminology)? Additionally, is it strict-aliasing-safe to read the value of "in->ptr" in the function "alg," and does the answer depend on if "in" and "out" are the same structure?

Comment: @68ejxfcj5669: Why don't you just read the standard? Instead of requiring  me to copy bits of it here?

Comment: "You know this is okay anyway, because when you wrote &in_arg your compiler implicitly converted the s1* to const s1*". I know that non-const pointers are convertible to const pointers, but it's not immediately obvious that they need have the same representation. For example, some implementation might add a tag bit to const-pointers that triggers a trap when written. Anyway, the real question at hand is about aliasing the structs s1 and s2. I could read the standard, but I've never understood how to interpret strict aliasing clauses.

Comment: @68ejxfcj5669: I think the passages I quoted are fairly clear.

Comment: Yes. It is now clear to me that the pointers have the same representation, and I can e.g. memcpy them. However, what is **not** clear to me is what this means for structures that contain differently qualified pointers. The question is about accesing s1 and s2 through pointers to the other type, but since the issue of pointer representation has been sorted, perhaps this is just another strict-aliasing question. Sorry if I have somehow offended you.

Comment: @68ejxfcj5669 You haven't "offended" me; I just don't see what's left to add. If you have two structures whose only members have identical layout, then clearly the two structures themselves have identical layout. I've added a couple more citations (C++14 only this time; you can find the equivalents in the other standards yourself!) if that helps...?

Comment: I'm not convinced that `void*` and `const void*` are layout-compatible, even after [CWG 1719](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1719) relaxed the rules in this area. "have the same representation and alignment requirements" != layout-compatible; the latter has a specific definition in the standard.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I thought about this further, and realized that the statements quoted indicate that "T" and "const T" are identical, not their pointers. Clause 3.9.2 (compound types) in a C++11 draft I found appears to be the relevant language: "Pointers to cv-qualified and cv-unqualified versions (3.9.3) of layout-compatible types shall have the same value representation and alignment requirements (3.11)."

Comment: @T.C. That's the part that I'm still unsure of as well. However, in a C++11 draft I found, there is a footnote 51 in section 3.9.3 (CV-qualifiers) that states "The same representation and alignment requirements are meant to imply interchangeability as arguments to functions,
return values from functions, and **non-static data members of unions.**" It's not clear to me if this implies layout compatibility though.

Comment: What else would "same representation" mean?